# Newtonsoft.Json конвертация из string в enum по имени

Tags: c#, json, newtonsoft.json

Есть следующий класс и enum:

```
public class Payment
{
   [JsonProperty("payment_type")]
   public PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
}
public enum PaymentType
{
    Success,
    WaitingForCapture,
    Canceled
}
```

Я получаю следующий json:

```
{
   "payment_type": "waiting_for_capture"
}
```

При попытке распарсить получаю ошибку: `Error converting value "waiting_for_capture" to type PaymentType. Requested value 'waiting_for_capture' was not found`

Я пытался исправить это добавлением атрибута `[JsonProperty("waiting_for_capture")]` над значением в enum, но это не помогло. Так же пытался в `JsonConverter.DeserializeObject(json, new StringEnumConverter())`, но это так же не помогло. Как решить проблему? Желательно без создания новых классов

Comment: [StringEnumConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_converters_stringenumconverter.htm), [Serialize with JsonConverters](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonConverters.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо было добавить `[EnumMember(Value = "waiting_for_capture)]` для того, чтобы `StringEnumConverter` мог десериализовать строку в нужный мне enum:

```
public enum PaymentType
{
    Success,
    [EnumMember(Value = "waiting_for_capture")]
    WaitingForCapture,
    Canceled
}
var result = JsonConverter.DeserializeObject(json, new StringEnumConverter());
```

Answer (score 1):

Если сериализовать следующим образом:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payment, new StringEnumConverter());
```

То результат будет:

```
{"payment_type":"WaitingForCapture"}
```

Соответственно, десериализация работает без проблем.

Полный код для примера:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
```

```
var payment = new Payment { PaymentType = PaymentType.WaitingForCapture };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payment, new StringEnumConverter());
Console.WriteLine(json);

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payment>(json);
Console.WriteLine(result.PaymentType);
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, что нужно было. API мне возвращает не просто `WaitingForCapture`, он возвращает мне `waiting_for_capture`, из-за `_` не десериализовывалось. Есть ли в newtonsoft какие-то настройки типа "заменить символ X на символ Y"?

Comment: @Kalmankantaja - если из чужого API приходит JSON, на формирование которого мы не можем повлиять, тогда да, нужен способ с указанием `EnumMember`.